# Active Record time series querying: comparing averages

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I would like to pull out `metric_id`s from my time series table, which have `AVG` on the column named `value` higher in the interval of the last 4 hours than in the last 24 hours. I have time series in my database in the following format:

```
row1 | metric_id: 1 | value: 22.2 | created_at: now
row2 | metric_id: 1 | value: 13.9 | created_at: now-1.hour
```

How is it possible with SQL (and preferably with help of Active Record) to perform such query that would perform `AVG(value)` operation on the table, grouped by `metric_id` created in the last 4 hours, and would return all `metric_id`s where `AVG(value)` in the last 24 hours is smaller?

I know I maybe could use help of filters:

```
 records =
 Record
  .select(:metric_id)
  .select("AVG(records.new_subscribers) FILTER (WHERE created_at between now() AND now() - interval '4 hours' AS four_hours")
  .select("AVG(records.new_subscribers) FILTER (WHERE created_at between now() AND now() - interval '1 day' AS one_day")
  .where("four_hours > one_day * 2.2")
  .group(:metric)
```

Could that really work and is there any better / nicer way to do it?